# Applying a rotation filter in IE8 and changing the aspect ratio

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a style like this:

```
.vertical-rotate{
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.00000000, 
     M12=-1.00000000, M21=1.00000000, M22=0.00000000,DX=32,sizingMethod='auto expand');
}
```

And I apply it dynamically to an image:

```
$("#rotate").click(function(e) { 
   e.preventDefault();
   $("img").addClass("vertical-rotate"); });
```

The problem is, with non-square images, the DOM renderer doesn't seem to realize that the aspect ratio has changed.  The image, which was previously centered, is now flush-right against its containing div.

This problem does *not* occur in IE9 or in real browsers (using their native rotate). Any ideas how I might tell IE8 to reposition the image properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although IE 8 doesn't recognise the updated width and height of the images, you can mimic the new sizes by setting their margins:

```
$("#rotate").click(function(e) { 
   e.preventDefault();
   var img = $("img").addClass("vertical-rotate");

   // On IE 8, fake image size by applying margins
   if ( $.browser.msie && $.browser.version >>> 0 === 8 ) {
     $.each( img, function ( i, e ) {
       e.style.marginRight  = e.height - e.width + 'px';
       e.style.marginBottom = e.width - e.height + 'px';
     });
   }
 });
```

EDIT: I assume you are using jQuery. If it is not, the browser detection and each function may need some modifications, but the general idea is there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the axis point that the rotation occurs on is different when using ie matrix. You actually have to rotate and translate it.

If you are already using javascript to add the class you may as well and use a plugin like http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/ to help.